# Evitar que al presionar el boton atras se vuelvan a llenar datos

Tags: php, back

les explico el problemilla que tengo.

Realice un sistema para emitir facturas que se conecta a la base de datos de una tienda en linea y mediante esta conexion saca algunos datos como el total, envio, etc.

Si el numero de pedido es correcto se muestra un formulario para que llenen sus datos fiscales, si el numero es erroneo o ya existe una factura emitida no muestra el formulario y muestra un error o un enlace de descarga de la factura según sea el caso.

El problema surge cuando se envia el formulario, se envia la peticion mediante POST a "invoice.php", este genera la factura, muestra los detalles de la misma y actualiza la base de datos para escribir el id de la factura y el estatus como 1 que es "Facturado" (Sirve para cuando escriben un pedido que ya fue facturado no pueda hacer otra factura"

Hasta este punto todo funciona bien, el problema es que si el cliente le da clic al boton retroceso en el navegador se regresa al formulario y este tiene de hecho aún todos los datos que el cliente ingreso y si le da clic al boton enviar se vuelve a emitir una factura nueva.

De que forma puedo evitar esto?

```
    //If status is null show error "Pedido no encontrado"
        if ($invoice_status == null) {
            echo "<center><h1>Pedido no encontrado</h1></center>";
        } 
    
        // If the value of the variable $order_id is not empty show the form from the example above with the values of the variables $order_id, $net_total, $tax_total, $shipping_total, $total_sales, $num_items_sold, $date_created

    elseif ($invoice_status == 0) {
        echo '<br><br><br><div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="form-view">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a href="https://www.hospitalveterinarioalbiter.com/" title="&lt;p&gt;Bienvenido al &lt;span style=&quot;color:#c9d2db;&quot;&gt; sistrema de facturación del&lt;/span&gt; Hospital veterinario Albiter  &lt;span style=&quot;color:#e8ebef;font-weight:bold;&quot;&gt; Powered by Soluciones Marva.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;" style="text-decoration:none"><span class="app-name">Hospital Veterinario Albiter</span></a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-container">
                                <div id="messages"></div>
                                <form action="invoice.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-app" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset class="row">
    
    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="legend">Solicitar factura</h3>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Paragraph Text -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Puede solicitar su factura llenando el siguiente formulario.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group required-control">
            <label  class="control-label" for="text_4">Nmero de orden</label>
            <input type="text" id="text_4" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'" data-alias="" class="form-control" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tal vez podrías añadir una validación en tu php invoice.php que verifique si la factura ya ha sido creada previamente.

Comment: Si se vuelve a emitir una factura nueva es porque no estas comprobando el valor del campo `order_id` en tu `invoice.php`, el cual deberia verificar en tu base de datos si ya existe la factura antes de volverla a crear. Si ya existe se la muestras, si no existe la creas.

Comment: Como primera opción: puedes en lugar de enviar a otra página en la misma pestana es abrir otra ***(target="_blank")***  con eso ya no existe la posibilidad de regresar,
segunda opción es: cada que entres a la página del formulario con JS limpiar todos los inputs

Comment: @masterguru y Óscar, Gracias a ambos, su respuesta fue la clave no se me había ocurrido validar en invoice.php el estatus de la factura, solo lo hacia en el formulario. Puse una respuesta con la solución, de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado :-), aunque en tu respuesta seria mejor que pusieras como validas el campo que lo que haces despues, pues no se ve de donde sale el $invoice_status y quien consulte esta pregunta no se si lo acabará de entender, pero haz lo que quieras, solo lo comento.  Y recuerda marcarla como aceptada (al cabo de 24 horas creo que lo permiten a las propias respuestas, no estoy seguro)

Comment: @masterguru Listo agregué los detalles faltantes, solo era la consulta a la BD realmente, pensé se daba por sentado. Si en 48 Horas, cuando me deje lo marco, gracias.

Comment: Comentario gratuito: No se si te has dado cuenta, pero si permites que los clientes pongan su order_id y este es consecutivo o facil de adivinar, es muy probable que a alguien le de por poner otros order_id a ver que sale, y ver facturas que no son suyas. Lo digo porque yo lo he hecho en alguna ocasión en algun proveedor que he tenido y luego he avisado de ese fallo de seguridad, pues son datos sensibles.

Comment: @masterguru SI lo tuve en cuenta, sin embargo del order_id solo recopila 4 datos y realmente solo se usa 1 de ellos los otros 3 solo se muestran, estos son: Precio antes de impuestos, precio de envio, impuestos y precio total, no hay ningún dato que sea sensible, el order_id no es consecutivo aunque si "facil" de adivinar, pero es el único dato que tiene el cliente para encontrar su pedido ya que como hay pedidos de invitado no se captura nombre por ejemplo o datos de direccion en productos digitales, en ese sentido creo estoy un poco amarrado de manos.

Comment: @masterguru en cuanto a una factura ya emitida la cosa se complica bastate para un curioso, porque aunque los order_id son "faciles" de adivinar, en Mexico casi nadie factura y tendria que estar bastante rato picando antes de encontrar una factura que por otro lado no tiene datos mas que de un negocio como su razon social o nombre y direccion fiscal que no siempre son datos de una vivienda y realmente creo todos los sistemas sufren de ese detalle, tal vez lo que podría hacer es que en vez de descargar la factura solo se envie por email al correo capturado pero a veces solo quieren descargar

Comment: @masterguru ando un poco liado con eso, le dare una vuelta y consultare con el cliente a ver que opina, me hiciste filosofar un rato jaja

Comment: je, bueno, que sepas que ahora lo sabe todo el mundo, pues desafortunadamente has puesto la url en la pregunta :-S... pero tranquilo, descansa primero y ya lo pensarás mejor cuando estes mas fresco. Mi consejo es: O bien el usuario debe identificarse primero y logeas lo que hace, por si hace eso y lo regañas despues, o bien lo que hago yo que es crear urls unicas concatenando diversos valores del registro de la factura y pasandolo por una función md5() para que me genere una cadena, y eso es lo que envio a los clientes para que vean la factura, o bien creas order_ids así o aleatorios

Comment: @masterguru tranquilo esa URL es de prueba jaja la tienda para la que se usaría el sistema es otro. Y si le dare una vuelta consultando con el cliente a ver que opina el, al final de cuentas el sistema lo usaran sus clientes.

Comment: jeje, perfecto, ya me habias asustado :-)  venga, suerte! saludos

Answer (score 1):

en efecto ya estaba algo agotado y no se me ocurrio validar en invoice.php si ya habia una factura lo solucione con el siguiente código:

```
//Validate if invoice_status in database is 1 or 0 

$sql = "SELECT invoice_status FROM ".$db_prefix."wc_order_stats WHERE order_id = '$order_id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$invoice_status = $row['invoice_status'];

//if is 1 show the invoice, if is 0 continue with the process
if ($invoice_status == 1) {
    echo '<center><br><br><br><h1>La factura ya fue emitida anteriormente</h1></center>';

// Create a request to get the invoice zip file, get the invoice_id from the previous request
    $url = 'https://www.api.com/v2/invoices/'.$invoice_id.'/zip';
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer $api_key",
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
// save the zip file to the server on the directory "invoices"
    $file = fopen("invoices/".$invoice_id.".zip", "w");
    fwrite($file, $response);
    fclose($file);
// create a button to download the zip file with class type input and class submit
    echo '<center><form action="invoices/'.$invoice_id.'.zip" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Descargar Factura">
  </form></center>';
} 

else {

//Ejecución del código para general la factura.
```